# Show $SO_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong\{A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) : A^tA = I, \det A = 1\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-isomorphism

> Show $SO_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong\{ A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) :  A^tA = I, \det A = 1\}$, where $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the group of rotations of the circle under the operation of composition.

Attempt: Suppose  $A =\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
  \end{bmatrix}$.

I have verified that $S = \{ A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) :  A^tA = I, \det A = 1\}$ is a subgroup of $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I was thinking to show define a function and show it's a bijective homomorphism to conclude the two groups are isomorphic to each other.

Let $\gamma : SO_2(\mathbb{R}) → S$.

define $\gamma(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
  \end{bmatrix}$.

I am confuse about how to define a function from $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ to $S$.

Can someone please help me? Any better approach would help or suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific? You have written down a map $\gamma$ already. I can't understand your confusion...

Comment: So I was not sure if that map $\gamma$ makes sense. Because I was having trouble defining elements from each group. Am I in the right track?

Comment: Ok, so you are saying $\theta \in S)_2(\mathbb R)$, what does that mean?

Comment: I am assuming rotational elements look like angles. I am not sure how elements look like .

Comment: I think that is good enough. If $\theta_1, \theta_2$ are two rotations in $S0_2(\mathbb R)$, what is the angle that represent the composition?

Comment: an orthogonal angle? I am not sure

Comment: If you first rotate by $\theta_1$, then by $\theta_2$, what is the resulting rotation?

Comment: It would be their sum $\theta_1 + \theta_2$

Comment: So I am kind of confuse if the angles in $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ will be the same angle in the matrix for the other group

Comment: You need to check that. You've have a map $\gamma$, you want to check if it is bijective and homomorphic.

Comment: @user420402 Use \{ \} instead of { } between $$.